# PIG latin Script - using group & TOBAG

Tags: hadoop

I have a file with following contents

INPUT:

```
TOYID;TOYSeries;ModuleID;ID;PART_NUMBER;SUPPLIER;LAND
394107;C204; 731305; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
394107;C204; 731307; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
394107;C204; 731315; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
394107;C204; 731325; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
394107;C204; 731335; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
394107;C204; 731345; 69807402;A0001532122;ABC;AT
```

I want output like this 
Output:

```
SUPPLIER;LAND; COUNT(SUPPLIER,LAND);  TOYID         TOYSeries;   ModuleID;   ID;          PART_NUMBER
ABC;AT;             6 ;               394107          C204;       731305; 69807402;      A0001532122
ABC;AT              6 ;               394107          C204;       731307; 69807402;      A0001532122
```

I tried:

```
A = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:8020/BigData_POC/....../TOY_Detail.txt' USING PigStorage(';') AS (TOYID:chararray,TOYSeries:chararray,ModuleID:chararray,ID:c‌​hararray,DESCRIPTION‌​:chararray,PART_NUMB‌​ER:chararray,SUPPLIE‌​R:chararray,LAND:cha‌​rarray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOYID,ModuleID,DESCRIPTION,PART_NUMBER,SUPPLIER,LAND;
C = GROUP B by (SUPPLIER,LAND);
D = foreach C generate group, COUNT(B) as cnt, B.TOYID,B.ModuleID,B.PART_NUMBER;
```

I am getting output like this:

> (SUPPLIER,LAND) COUNT {(TOYID) (TOYID) (TOYID)...(TOYID) (MODULEID) (MODULEID) (MODULEID)... (MODULEID)(PARTNUMBER) (PARTNUMBER)... (PARTNUMBER)}

Do you know any pig latin script available for this?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, could you try this as a solution ? I have not verified it myself so may need some tweak as well.

```
D = foreach C generate group, COUNT(B) as cnt; 
E = foreach D generate group.supplier as supplier, group.land as land, cnt;
F = Join B by (supplier,land),E by (supplier,land)
```

Comment: I have tried this , its working fine. but am getting duplicate columns for SUPPLIER, LAND .

Comment: That is how you have wrote your expected output in your question.

Comment: Thanks Amit for your help.

Comment: Could you please mark this as answer if it helps answering your question ?